# Queueable Apex vs process builder and Flow

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow, queueable-apex

Here is the scenario:

On insert of a record/records of Object - `Apartment__c` and conditions like `Floor>7 AND Num_Of_Appt > 200(has like 4-5 conditions that should be met)` , I should Query the `BuildingType__c` record where Name `NOT EQUALS` `'House'`( there can be many) and create a new record of type `Unit__c` for each `BuildingType__c`. The Unit__c has two lookups 1. to `Apartment__c` 2. to `BuildingType__c`.

The above case needs to be done for Apartment that meets a different type of criteria and should be associate with `BuildingType__c` `EQUALS` `"Non House"`( Create `Unit__c` record for each non house `BuildingType__c`)

I have two options to do this:

1. `via trigger and on after insert it will enqueue a queueable job`( this process can happen asyn) - This is much easier. Can be achieved by jus a SQOL + for inside a for loop. Can be achieved in few lines of code + it will be async and will be more efficient.
2. `via process builder + Cloud Flow` - it is declarative but requires some more effort to create process builder + flow and to loop through each `BuildingType__c` and create a record `Unit__c` for each one of them.

According to me `Queueable` is less effort and is async so more efficient. Any comments on which will be a good approach in terms of maintainability, scalability and efficiency.

Comment: Process Builder flows are VERY inefficient in terms of CPU usage. We are in the process of converting a bunch of these into trigger/Apex code because we hit CPU limits far too often.

Comment: (BTW, if by "Appartment" you mean a separate dwelling in a shared building, that's spelled "Apartment"...)

Comment: lol updated - Apartment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apex is superior in all three categories for maintainability, scalability, and efficiency. Flows typically take longer to edit than code, do not run efficiently, and may cause problems on bulk updates. If you're given a choice, prefer using Apex when possible. Flows are really only meant for *simple* logic.

Comment: As one of the product managers of Flow, I use it a great deal. I also write a lot of Apex code. Apex code will always execute the most quickly, but Flow brings many other advantages to the table. Code requires talented developers to build and maintain, and Flow is much easier to get into and learn, especially with recent enhancements like the debugger. While Apex Code is mature and not really changing, Flow is evolving rapidly. Example: upcoming features will reduce the clicks needed to do some flow actions by 50%. In fact, internal dev teams at Salesforce are increasingly developing on Flow.

Comment: @AlexEdelstein I can't comment on the future state of the product, only what we have today. And today, Flows are at least serviceable, compared to the previous versions. Compared to the initial release and previous iterations, my stance has slowly migrated from "run away as fast as you can" to "use for simple logic". I look forward to the day I can enthusiastically endorse Flows over Apex, and I believe Salesforce can get there. I've replied to your email, and look forward to having a conversation with you about the future and what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Fast-forward a few years from this comment and I think we can all agree on the amount of effort and focus that has been put into Flow.

But to add my short comment to this, it's not one or the other but the blend of both that is the most powerful. Extending Flow capability with writing discrete Invocable Actions is the best of both worlds. The 'self documenting' and easier to visualise nature of Flow coupled with the raw power of Apex underpinning it.